# XSLT plugin for jquery always sets the field to blank

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, xslt

I have the following div, which is used as a jquery modal dialog.

```
<div id="searchResultsDialog" title="Search Results">
    <div id="searchResults"></div>
</div>
```

Then I have the following code to populate that div with the results of an xsl transformation, where both the xml and xsl strings can be verified that they contain the correct data.

```
$("#searchResults").xslt({
    xml: resultXML,
    xsl: result.xml
});
```

Whenever I run this, I never end up with any data transformed.  I stepped through the plugin in the debugger, and the value returned by the .xlst function is the empty string.  I know that the xsl and xml work fine together, because if I simply tie the stylesheet to the xml and display it in the browser, it works great.  Note also that I'm not receiving any errors.

I've also tried using Sarissa, but I always end up getting an alert box stating msxml6.dll:  .

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong, or what I'm missing?  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm also open to other client side xslt implementations.

Comment: Have you verified, using a separate XSL transformer, that your stylesheet is working correctly on the input?  For Windows Microsoft has a freely available XML Notepad that will do this.  *nix you could use Xalan or Saxon on the command line.

Comment: Yes, I've taken the xml output, saved it to an xml file, and tied the xsl stylesheet directly to the xml file by:      <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="template.xslt"?>.  It transforms correctly in both IE8 and XML Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by moving away from the xslt plugin and simply doing a crossbrowser load.